# DateFormat in radGridViewDataColumn WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, radgridview

I'm working on `WPF MVVM` application with `telerik` controls. I need to format one of the column to Date(`MM/dd/yyyy`). When i select a date from the calendar it works fine and after switching to next column the value is showed as `MM/dd/yyyy 12:00:00`. I dont need the time to be displyed along.

//Code:

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="ApprvdDate" DataMemberBinding="{Binding ApprovedDate, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DataFormatString="{}{0: MM/dd/yyyy}">                                                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellEditTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<telerik:RadDatePicker Name="ClrDatePicker" SelectedDate="{Binding ApprovedDate, Mode=TwoWay}" AllowDrop="True"> 
</telerik:RadDatePicker>
</DataTemplate>
</telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellEditTemplate>
</telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
```

where `ApprovedDate` is `string` object in the collection.

The `DataFormatString` doesn't work. I tried changing many formats.

Also tried as,

```
DataFormatString="{0: MM/dd/yyyy}"
```

which throws compilation error.

Where i'm wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using simply `MM/dd/yyyy` without the `{0: ... }` syntax?

Comment: No change, it seems the property isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to expose `ApprovedDate` as a `DateTime` property instead of a `string` - `DataFormatString` will only work correctly on that type.

Either that or wherever you are converting to `string`, use the format string you require instead of a simple `.ToString()` call by calling `.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in C#

```
ApprovedDate.Date.toString("MM/dd/yyy")
```